# Installing LASTools to QGIS on a Mac (or other LAS processing plugins)

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, lidar, mac, las

I recently saw [this link](http://rapidlasso.com/2013/09/29/how-to-install-lastools-toolbox-in-qgis/) how to install LAStools toolbox to QGIS. The problem is that the instructions are only for Windows users. Now I wonder if it's possible to install LAStools on a Mac with QGIS or if there are any other LAS plugins that could be used on a mac?

Comment: One option: http://rapidlasso.com/2014/10/04/using-lastools-on-mac-os-x-with-wine/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can install [libLAS](http://www.liblas.org/index.html):

- compiling it ([Using “XCode” on OS X](http://www.liblas.org/compilation.html#using-xcode-on-os-x))
- installing it with Homebrew ([Homebrew Formulas: Liblas](http://brewformulas.org/Liblas))

Or you can use GRASS [GRASS GIS Wiki: Lidar](http://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/LIDAR) or [Cloud Compare](http://www.danielgm.net/cc/) with a new  Mac OS X port [Mac OS X: CloudCompare](http://asmaloney.com/software/)

[image]

Comment: Tried installing libLAS before with Homebrew but got into trouble. Now it works! Is it possible to use libLAS inside QGIS?

Comment: Yeah libLAS != LASlib

Comment: Does not answer the question. In fact it gives some really bad misleading advice. libLAS was a dead project even at the time of this post and does not support the 1.4 spec released in 2003.

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution which sounds promising even though it's not really a Mac version.

http://rapidlasso.com/2014/10/04/using-lastools-on-mac-os-x-with-wine/

Comment: Please elaborate a little bit more. Otherwise, it will be deleted.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/123727)

Comment: I'll turn this answer into a comment of my own original post instead